# Road Name windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I will sound like absolutely a noob, but I am so stressed out that I am not able to do any research properly.

Basically I got 127 road names in a list, and I want to display them one by one in a random sequence in a label and I will answer them if its right one increment to green box if its wrong then increment to yellow box but at same time it will display me right answer in a label and then on pressing submit button it will take me to next road name, here is what I have done until now,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RL = RoadLocationNames();
        i = 1;
        red = 1;
        y = 1;
    }

    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> RL;
    int i,red, y;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.Next(RL.Count);

        lbLocation.Text = RL.ElementAt(r).Key;

        if (tbRoad.Text.ToLower() == RL.ElementAt(r).Value.ToLower())
        {
            Green.Text = i.ToString();
            i++;
            RL.Remove(RL.ElementAt(r));
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = RL.ElementAt(r).Value.ToString();
            Red.Text = i.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        Yellow.Text = y.ToString();
        y++;

    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> RoadLocationNames()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> RLNs = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
        RLNs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Road Name", "Location Name"));

        return RLNs;
    }
```

Now My internet is so slow that I barely can upload any screenshot of my form but I will try to.. I got exam tomorrow and I want to do preparation using this app, but I am not sure about,

- How to display a road name instead of (road name and its answer which is what my code is doing now) it could be because I am doing everything in buttton submit, I need help with logic and code (sorry but am in rush)

[image: I need quick response with code please]

Comment: What is the red box for?

Comment: Then what is the yellow box for?

Comment: It seems yellow box is for total answers.

Comment: @Coder it looks like that, but the question says the yellow box is for wrong answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because you're doing everything in your submit. I suggest you split your code into the following:

1. Initialisation - create the list of road names and locations, then run setup (next step).
2. Setup - Clear the user's current answer, pick a road name/location pair randomly and display the question part on the form.
3. User submission - check answer, increment appropriate counter, if the answer is right run setup again, otherwise display what the answer should have been.

Initialisation can be done in your form constructor. Setup should be a private method. User submission should be your click handler.

(It looks like you're incrementing `i` for both right and wrong answers which is probably incorrect. This is why you pick better variable names than a single letter to make mistakes like that more obvious.)